# Change a XML file using Bash

Tags: linux, xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">1</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">1</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">2</property>
      <property name="connection.db">3</property> 
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And need to change the "property name=connection.db" to 4 using Bash.

Already tried

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/hibernate-configuration/session-factory/property[@name='connection.db']" -v '4' test1.config
```

and

```
xmlstarlet ed -u  "//session-factory/property[@name='db']" -v '4' test1.config
```

But neither works.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first xmlstarlet works fine. Is the problem that the file is not modified? xmlstarlet has a "global option" `--inplace` for the `ed` command

Comment: The second one fails because the attribute value is not "db" it's "connection.db"

Comment: the first one has no errors , but the file dint changed even with -L

Comment: What's your `xmlstarlet --version`?

Comment: `xmlstarlet ed -L -u "/hibernate-configuration/session-factory/property[@name='connection.db']" -v '4' test.xml` works just fine and prints the modifed xml to stdout.

Comment: @treuss, with `-L`, you should see nothing on stdout.

Comment: carriage returns maybe?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I update my question, I had forgotten "xmlns". it doesn't work with "xmlns="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for the namespace. Try

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N x="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" -u "//x:session-factory//x:property[@name='connection.db']" -v "4"  test1.config
```

Comment: Or If you're using xmlstarlet version 1.0.5 or later, you can use `_` as the prefix in your XPath instead of binding it to a prefix with `-N`. Example: `//_:session-factory/_:property[@name='db']`